# Match 2 sets of columns on a ONE-to-ONE basis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matching, one-to-one

I have 2 sets of columns in MATLAB that need to be matched.  There are quite a few ways to do it if the mapping doesn't has to be `one-to-one`.  My example below would illustrate what I'm trying to do

```
mat1 = [ 100  734567 500 734567 23
         1011 734568 200 734568 11
         1011 734568 200 734568 23
         1011 734568 200 734568 23
         1011 734568 200 734568 34
         1111 734569 300 734569 34 ] ; % ignore last column

mat2 = [ 1011 734568 200  734568
         1011 734568 200  734568
         1011 734568 100  734568
         1111 734569 300  734569  ] ;
```

I need to remove those rows from Mat1 that were ***found*** in Mat2 as well based on columns 1,2,3,4.  Result:

```
mat1 = [ 100  734567 500 734567 23
         1011 734568 200 734568 23
         1011 734568 200 734568 34 ] ;
```

A probable solution was to include row_ids 1,2,3.. for unique rows as shown below but I couldn't implement the same.  Thanks for your help!  The actual data sets are big and so a vectorized solution is preferred!

```
mat2 = [ 1011 734568 200  734568 1 
         1011 734568 200  734568 2
         1011 734568 100  734568 1
         1111 734569 300  734569 1
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think what you want is this:

```
mat1(~ismember(mat1(:,1:size(mat2,2)),mat2,'rows'),:)
```

However, your example result confuses me. Second and third rows of your result are present in `mat2` (ignoring last column),  so they should be removed, right?

Comment: --> for id 1011, row 1,2,3 matched exactly with the set in mat2.  But since mat2 had only 2 of these rows, only 2 of them were deleted from mat1.  Please let me know if it is still unclear.